# Django Redirect to a view with ajax call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, redirect, django-views

I have a Django application. Inside it, I use some Ajax calls to a function when I would like to manipulate backend, without affecting the front end.

In one function I would like to redirect the user to a home page.

I have:

```
def some_function(request, param_one):
    other_function(request.user, param_one)
    return redirect('mypage:home')
```

and in JS I have:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : '/url to my function/',
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error complete');
        }
});
```

I see that I get the right page in chrome developer tools

[image]

But nothing happened... So js get the HTML page but didn't render it.

Comment: Why are you using Ajax at all if you want to redirect? Why not just use a standard form and return a redirect from there?

Comment: You can return the url in the ajax call, if it is dependent on the data processed. or else you can just call `window.location = "http://example.com";` in the success function

Comment: redirecting on the server side, will not change the users current page, because it is a ajax call, if you want to redirect like this, then as @DavitTovmasyan said, dont do an ajax, just submit the form as is.

Comment: I use Ajax call because logic is more complex,... only if some specific acute, redirect should happen, else return data to the view,...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
def some_function(request, param_one):
    other_function(request.user, param_one)
    return render(request,'mypage:home')
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : '/url to my function/',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response; 
            #replace the id of div where you want to show fetched data
        }
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error complete');
        }
});
```